# Core Data: load binary property lazy/only when accessed

Tags: core-data

I have a pretty big list (several thousand entrires) of elements which contain a binary property where a PDF document is stored (can be up to several MB).

How can I fetch all the elements but the binary property not immediately but only when it is accessed via `element.document`?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would save the PDF to the local filesystem, and store only the folder/filename in CoreData.  (Note, you should store only the folder and filename relative to the Documents directory (or other defined folder) rather than the full path to the file, because the Documents folder can actually change (eg. with new builds of your app).

If for some reason you don’t want to go that route, you could replace the attribute with a to-one relationship to a new, separate entity which has only one attribute for the PDF data.  Relationships are by default not faulted in, even when the originating object is faulted.